# Как сделать что бы при нажатии на кнопку(.razvernut_debet) открывался див(.bl_card_sebet_raskr) не во всех блоках а в одном свой, в другом свой?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать что бы при нажатии на кнопку(.razvernut_debet) открывался див(.bl_card_sebet_raskr) не во всех блоках а в одном свой, в другом свой?
html:

```
<div class="razv_debet">
            <div class="a_ico_debet">
                <a href="#" class="razvernut_debet razvernut_debet_1">Развернуть детали <svg class="treug_svg">
                        <use xlink:href="#treug_svg"></use>
                    </svg>
                </a>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="but_debet">Подать заявку</a>
        </div>
        <div class="bl_card_sebet_raskr">
            <p class="p_card_sebet_raskr">saddddddddddddddddddasdasd</p>
        </div>

второй блок:
<div class="razv_debet">
            <div class="a_ico_debet">
                <a href="#" class="razvernut_debet razvernut_debet_1">Развернуть детали <svg class="treug_svg">
                        <use xlink:href="#treug_svg"></use>
                    </svg>
                </a>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="but_debet">Подать заявку</a>
        </div>
        <div class="bl_card_sebet_raskr">
            <p class="p_card_sebet_raskr">saddddddddddddddddddasdasd</p>
        </div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.razvernut_debet').click(function(){
        $('.bl_card_sebet_raskr').slideToggle(300);      
        return false;
    });
});
```

сss:

```
.bl_card_sebet_raskr {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуете вот так.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.razvernut_debet').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.razv_debet').next(".bl_card_sebet_raskr").slideToggle(300);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="razv_debet">
  <div class="a_ico_debet">
    <a href="#" class="razvernut_debet razvernut_debet_1">Развернуть детали <svg class="treug_svg">
                        <use xlink:href="#treug_svg"></use>
                    </svg>
                </a>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="but_debet">Подать заявку</a>
</div>
<div class="bl_card_sebet_raskr">
  <p class="p_card_sebet_raskr">saddddddddddddddddddasdasd</p>
</div>

второй блок:
<div class="razv_debet">
  <div class="a_ico_debet">
    <a href="#" class="razvernut_debet razvernut_debet_1">Развернуть детали <svg class="treug_svg">
                        <use xlink:href="#treug_svg"></use>
                    </svg>
                </a>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="but_debet">Подать заявку</a>
</div>
<div class="bl_card_sebet_raskr">
  <p class="p_card_sebet_raskr">saddddddddddddddddddasdasd</p>
</div>
```

Comment: При нажатии не чего не происходит так

Comment: Обновил код, посмотрите